# EF Code First Migrations: SetInitializer and Initialize

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am working on Code First Migration and Im trying work with code based migrations (Automatedmigration=false). What I can to do now it's:

-Run Enable Migrations

-Add migration Initial

-Run migrations using "Update Database" (To create the migrationhistory table)

-Make changes in my model

-Execute Add Migration "changesInMyModel"

Now what i am trying to do is be able to run all my migrations automatically.
using something like:

```
[Test] 
public void UpdateDataModel()
{
 Database.SetInitializer(
 new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyConfiguration>());
 var dc = new MyContext();
 dc.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

After to execute the test and go to the database i can't see any of my changes.
What Can i do?     advices are welcome!

UPDATE:
Myconfiguration class is using Automatedmigration=false.

MyConfiguration class is public and visible outside of its parent project.

I am not using any configuration in the app.config since that I am using  Database.SetInitializer from the source code.

Before to run my test MigrationHistory is created

Running update database from package manager console the migrations run fine.

UPDATE:
I am running a version modified (using code based migration) of the example bellow:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx , but the probleme is still there.
- Enable migration
- Add migration
- Try SetInitializer and Initialize but nothing happen.

UPDATE:
- SetInitializer and Initialize working fine when Automatedmigration=true, the changes in the model are sync with the db.
- Using the code bellow works.

```
new DbMigrator(new Configuration()).Update(); What should be the difference?
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? Make sure `dc.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` is what you're expecting.

Comment: yes, it's working with the right connection string :)

Comment: I have couple posts on that (and a migration initializer etc.) - but you need to post your initializer - that's the main thing. Otherwise that works w/o problems (other problems, not this one)

Comment: @NSGaga sorry, but i don't understand your comment. is not enough my test code?. This is the place where currently I am working, just a unit test (since i don't have any user interface application yet).
may be you mean my dataContext and myconfiguration class?

Comment: sorry my bad :) I misread the 'initializer' line. Ok - if you already ran `Add-Migration` nothing `will` happen if you try to do it from the code - is that what you're doing? To actually test it - you'd need to clean the Db first, then run migration / initializer from code. Other than that, the test should run ok.

Comment: What currently i am doing it's (having my migrationhistory table created):
1) Make changes in the model
 
2)Run Add-Migration (system ask for a name, so i give one)

3) Having a new migration class inside of migration folder I try run my test. sadly nothing happen and the database schema is not including my last changes in the model. 
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstod the task of MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, 
Migrate the database to the latest according to the migrations clases inside migration folder.. am i right?

Comment: you're right. Did you make sure the 'recompile' the app. And what's the connection again. That can change if your test app has different config. Try with EnableAutomaticMigrations on/off just to check. Try putting try-catch to make sure no errors. And try running `DbMigrator` directly `new DbMigrator(new Configuration).Update()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28696/discussion-between-rolando-and-nsgaga)

Comment: yeah, SetInitializer and Initialize working fine when Automatedmigration=true, Where I should run new DbMigrator(new Configuration).Update() ?.

Comment: you shouldn't - just to test, instead of initializer - where you call Initialize

Comment: using new DbMigrator(new Configuration()).Update(); works! 
What could be the error?

Comment: you mean what was the problem? I'm not sure - is it the `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` or `DbMigrator` that solved it? one or both? Migration should work w or w/o that flag. And DbMigrator does exactly what that initializer does. If you can post the full test project I'll run and test. And I could put this as an answer, since it helped - but I'm not sure what helped really :)

Comment: What i mean with :"What could be the error? " is:
What is the difference betwen DbMigration().Update and Initiziaze... 
anyway.. during my day (or night) .. I will atach in somewhere a very simple sample of my code.

Comment: no difference - this is the source code (not same EF ver - but I think it's the same) - [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion%60.cs). Just @ me here - as I saw this by chance.

Comment: @NSGaga as I see your code (new DbMigrator(new Configuration).Update()) it'working you should post your comment as answer ;). thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Rolando - I just posted what I wrote in here (as that's all I can tell, I still have no idea why it worked but probably some 'micro-specific' of your code). Glad it helped, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And just to update based on our comments in the thread...

**This solved the problem** - but to be frank **I'm still not sure why it did** :)

> Try with **`EnableAutomaticMigrations`** on/off just to check. Try putting
>   try-catch to make sure no errors. And try running DbMigrator directly
>   **`new DbMigrator(new Configuration()).Update()`** –

...and additional comments

> Migration should work w or w/o that flag. And DbMigrator does exactly
>   what that initializer does. There seems to be no difference - this is
>   the source code (not same EF ver - but I think it's the same) -
>   [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion%60.cs).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you should try to place the code below under `protected void Application_Start()` in the `Global.asax.cs`. This way, you database connection will always be Initialized before everything else.

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", 
           "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Maybe this [Pro Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430242361/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d1_i1?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0GT0AEF53271XFH1Z88N&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375923922&pf_rd_i=915398) will help you set up your testing project. There is also an [MVC 3 version](http://www.amazon.ca/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-Third/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1366682340&sr=1-1&keywords=MVC%203), but they will pretty much say the same thing. They suggest to use [Moq Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq), and its helped me in the past.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, the thing is that I am not working on asp.net mvc yet.. I just working on Domain/DAL project and a test project :)

Comment: @Rolando i added some more information, maybe that will help. But when you finally start working on your MVC project, don't forget to set the Initializer as suggested.